# Given an unbalanced chemical equation, is it possible to determine the largest possible coefficient that could be used in the balanced equation?

Tags: equilibrium, computational-chemistry, stoichiometry

I am writing a program to balance chemical equations, and would love to know if there is an algebraic way to determine the greatest possible coefficient that I would need to check.

Comment: I think you might just want to use matrices...

Answer (score 7):

## In short

Just use matrices.

## In long

Consider this equation to be balanced:

$$\ce{CuSCN + KIO3 + HCl -> CuSO4 + KCl + HCN + ICl + H2O}$$

([source with spoiler](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080530150323AA8tQMu))

We are trying to solve this equation:

$$\ce{aCuSCN + bKIO3 + cHCl -> dCuSO4 + eKCl + fHCN + gICl + hH2O}$$

Now, we move every term to the left hand side (warning: handwavey chemistry):

$$\ce{aCuSCN + bKIO3 + cHCl - dCuSO4 - eKCl - fHCN - gICl - hH2O = 0}$$

Transform into matrix form (the element names are just for reference):

$$
\begin{matrix}
\ce{Cu}\\
\ce{S}\\
\ce{C}\\
\ce{N}\\
\ce{K}\\
\ce{I}\\
\ce{O}\\
\ce{H}\\
\ce{Cl}
\end{matrix}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1&0 \\
0 &3 &0 &-4&0 &0 &0 &-1\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &-2\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &-1&0 &-1&0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
f\\
g\\
h
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Notice that the biggest matrix is **not a square**. You must transform it to a square. If the elements are in excess (just like this case), add variables; otherwise, add elements. Set the extra variables/elements to zero:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\ce{Cu}\\
\ce{S}\\
\ce{C}\\
\ce{N}\\
\ce{K}\\
\ce{I}\\
\ce{O}\\
\ce{H}\\
\ce{Cl}
\end{matrix}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-1&0 &0 \\
0 &3 &0 &-4&0 &0 &0 &-1&0 \\
0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &-1&0 &-2&0 \\
0 &0 &1 &0 &-1&0 &-1&0 &0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
f\\
g\\
h\\
i
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

**Note**: $i$ must be zero.

Now you can use any algorithm for solving homogeneous square matrix equations to continue.

Comment: There is no guarantee that any solver gives exact integer multiples and if the matrix is singular (as in your example) simply scaling the result vector won't necessarily work either. You will actually need to use an integer matrix solver. A Gaussian elimination with pivoting that only uses integer multipliers for instance should do this correctly. The smallest common multiplier of all matrix entries should provide the upper bound.

Comment: Also don't pad matrices to make them square. It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Matrices, as shown in DHMO's answer, provide a way to solve systems of linear equations.  But I think that, for most students, it might be more accessible to just solve the simultaneous linear equations directly.

Specifically:  We know that, in a balanced chemical equation, the number of atoms of each element on the left must equal the number of atoms of each element on the right.  Thus, for each element, we can write an equation expressing that.

Consider, for instance:

$$\ce{a H_2 + b O_2 -> c H_2O}$$

Based on the hydrogens, we know that $a=c$.  And based on the oxygens, we know that $2 b = c$.  [To get the number of oxygens, you need to multiple the coefficient for the molecule, $b$, times the number of oxygens in the molecule, $2$.]

Using simple substitution, we know that $a = 2 b =c$. Hence if we pick the smallest possible integer, $1$, for $b$, we have: $a = c = 2$, and thus:

$$\ce{2H_2 + O_2 -> 2 H_2O}$$

Now let's apply this to a non-trivial example, say that in DHMO's answer:

$$\ce{aCuSCN + bKIO3 + cHCl -> dCuSO4 + eKCl + fHCN + gICl + hH2O}$$

For this reaction, our simultaneous equations for each element would be:

Cu, S: $a = d$

K: $b = e$

I: $b = g$

C, N: $a = f$

Cl: $c = e + g$

H: $c = f + 2h$

O: $3b = 4d + h$

If you solve this set of simultaneous equations, either manually, or using an equation solver that can be restricted to integer solutions, then you will get the balanced chemical equation shown here:

> $$\ce{4CuSCN + 7KIO3 + 14HCl -> 4CuSO4 + 7KCl + 4HCN + 7ICl + 5H2O}$$

I obtained this with Mathematica, using the following code:

Reduce[$a == d$ && $b == e$ && $b == g$ && $a == f$ && $c == e + g$ &&
$c == f + 2 h$ && $3 b == 4 d + h$, Integers]